# Unable to unlock Asus Zenphone 3 bootloader

Tags: twrp, asus-zenfone-3

tried unlocking using official APK as well as the unofficial .
https://forum.xda-developers.com/zenfone-3/how-to/zenfone-3-ze520kl-ze552kl-unofficial-t3738811
https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/zenfone3/install

I guess bootloader is not unlocked, although it said unlocked. Any other way to unlock the bootloader or troubleshoot the unlock

```
###############################################################################
#                                                                             #
#                           Device Unlocked                                   #
#                                                                             #
###############################################################################
< waiting for device >



...
(bootloader)    Device tampered: false
(bootloader)    Device unlocked: false
(bootloader)    Device critical unlocked: false
(bootloader)    Charger screen enabled: true
(bootloader)    Display panel:
(bootloader)    Device is_authorized: false
(bootloader)    ssn_num: G9AZCY05W199BPD
(bootloader)    isn_num: N0CY1637MB0028482
(bootloader)    check_fused: 0
(bootloader)    Device resize: false
(bootloader)    BOOT_COUNT : 466
(bootloader)    SB=Y
(bootloader)    Re-partition: false
(bootloader)    Device had been rooted: NO
(bootloader)    Device has copy fsg to fsgCA: false
(bootloader)    Device last copy fsg status: fail
(bootloader)    verity_mode: 1
(bootloader)    is_ffu: false
(bootloader)    verity_counter: 0
(bootloader)    total verity_counter: 0
OKAY [  0.211s]
finished. total time: 0.212s



target reported max download size of 534773760 bytes
sending 'recovery' (21090 KB)...
OKAY [  0.511s]
writing 'recovery'...
FAILED (status read failed (Too many links))
finished. total time: 0.663s
```

Comment: thx for sharing the unlock tutorials. you are right, the message "Device Unlocked" is just a hard-coded text and not actually confirmed unlock status

Comment: i tried unlocking a Rog Phone 2 the other day... didnt work either... didnt really try though, ill try again in a few days (i work at a phone repair/resale factory... im quite busy)